# "Node Commands" printed at prompt when trying to run grunt/ gulp on Windows 7

Tags: npm

I've installed nodejs, and have used npm to install grunt using
npm install grunt

When I try to run grunt, I am presented with what appears to be instructions on running node commands: (see image)

the same applies when trying to run gulp

I have done the same steps on other computers, and had no problem running grunt previously
[image][image]

Please suggest ideas as to what's going on.
Thanks

Comment: Looks like you have a different application called `node` on your system path that's getting run instead of Node.js. Also, if you want to run grunt from the command line like that, you need to install it globally: `npm install grunt -g`

Comment: ah... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29579401/nodejs-seems-to-be-not-working-npm-do-work-however

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by Joe Clay, the problem was that there was another app called node.exe whose pathwas in PATH variable before nodejs.

see also:

[Nodejs seems to be not working; npm do work, however](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29579401/nodejs-seems-to-be-not-working-npm-do-work-however)